# Unable to print log when boot is completed

Tags: android

I am unabe to load a message(log) when boot is completed. I have tried with below code:

In BootReceiver.java file:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Booting Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("On Boot Load", "Boot loading");

    }

}
```

In Services.java file:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Service", "Updating Services");
    return null;
    }
}
```

I have also added with below code in menifes.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I run the app the log does not appear in logcat section.

Comment: Have you run your app at least once after installation, before rebooting? That Receiver won't work until then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onStartCommand()` implementation:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Service", "Updating Services");
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent pIntent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("On Boot Load", "Boot loading");
        return super.onStartCommand(pIntent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Also beware of other filter like `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON`.

---

I use this code (without a service) and it works for me (just tested it):

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

*Kotlin:*

```
class MyBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == ACTION) {
            Logger.warning("BOOTING UP!")
        }
    }

    companion object {

        const val ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"

    }

}
```

Comment: I have implemented onStartCommand() as well but still couldn't print logs in logcat

Comment: Strange. I have implemented this many times already. Please watch closely at your logcat.

Comment: I just want to print a log on logcat.. can you please show me your code which does work for you

Comment: Posted my simple code without a service. Please pay attention to your complete logcat when it boots up because I suspect your Service to be the root of your problem. The boot receiver is solid and working. Don't you see anything using `adb logcat '*:W'` during boot?

Answer (score 0):

The receiver tag should be inside application tag and the uses-permission tag should be outside application tag but inside of manifest tag.